# Selenium Java Failed to start browser selenium3.6, firefox v56 gecko v19

Tags: selenium, firefox

I got the below error and Firefox failed to be launched, I am using Selenium Java Bindings v3.6.0 and Firefox v56.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxEtR.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S0ym.png)

The error is :

```
INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\monaly\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.FEt42xwspukL"
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Failed to start browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe: other os error
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `import` from :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
```

Change to :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

### Update :

As you are still facing `SessionNotCreatedException` with `other os error`, I would suggest to

1. Uninstall `Firefox Browser` through `Revo Uninstaller`.
2. Run `CCleaner` to wipe off all the OS chores.
3. Take a `System Reboot`.
4. Execute the `Test`.